# Prove that there exists $k \in \mathbb R$ and a smooth function $g: S^1 \to \mathbb R$ s.t. $\alpha - k d\varphi = dg$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

Here's a practice prelims problem from my university:

> (a) Consider the $1$-form $\alpha = \sin^2 \varphi d\varphi$ on $S^1$ ($0 \leq \varphi \leq 2\pi$). Compute $\int_{S_1}\alpha$.
>
> (b) Prove that there does not exist a smooth function $g: S^1 \to \mathbb R$ s.t. $\alpha = dg$
>
> (c) Prove that there exists $k \in \mathbb R$ and a smooth function $g: S^1 \to \mathbb R$ s.t. $\alpha - k d\varphi = dg$. Find all possible $k$ and $g$ with this property.

Parts (a) and (b) are easy. (b) just uses a proof by contradiction using the fundamental theorem of calculus. However, I don't know how to solve part (c): Is there a standard method for this?

Comment: Hint: $\sin^2\varphi=\frac{1-\cos(2\varphi)}2.$

Comment: @OolongMilktea That gives one value of $g$ and $k$, yes. But what can we say about "all possible" values of $k$ and $g$? That's what I'm confused about.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for your hint. Using what Oolong says, is there only one possible value of $k$ and $g$?

Comment: 1) I don't understand at all what @OolongMilktea 's comment has to do with your exercise. 2) even if you didn't yet find a solution, you can easily prove its uniqueness (up to additive constants for $g$).

Comment: @AnneBauval I mistake $\alpha$ as $\phi\sin^2\phi d\phi$. I deleted it.

Comment: @OolongMilktea $\phi\sin^2\phi d\phi$ is not a well-defined 1-form on $S^1$, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin^2\varphi=\frac{1-\cos(2\varphi)}2$$
hence a solution is
$$k=\frac12,\;g(\varphi)=-\frac14\sin(2\varphi).$$
It is unique (up to additive constants for $g$) because if $(c,h)$ is the difference of two solutions then
$-cd\varphi=dh,$ hence $c=0$ and $h=$constant.